# Too many open files: how many are open, what they are, and how many can the JVM open

Tags: java, jvm

I'm getting this exception in Java:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Too many open files)
```

I'm looking for the ways to eliminate this problem.

This error obviously indicates that JVM has allocated too many handles and underlying OS won't let it have more. Either I've got leak somewhere with improperly closed connections/streams.

This process runs for days non-stop and eventually throws the exception. It repeatedly happens after 12-14 days of up-time.

How do you fight this? Is there a way to get a list of allocated handles in JVM or track when it hits certain amount? I'd love to have them printed and see how it grows and when. I can't use a profiler because it's a production system and have difficulties to reproduce it in development. Any suggestion?

I am monitoring free heap size and raising an "alarm" when it approaches 1% of the total specified in -Xmx. I also know that if my thread count hits above 500, then something definitely goes out of hand. Now, **is there a way to know that** my JVM allocates **too many handles** from OS and doesn't give them back, e.g. sockets, opened files, etc. If I'd knew that, I'd know where to look and when.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the JVM and OS?

Also, I suggest that you put more effort into reproducing this in a development environment. It can be a hassle, but when you have such a problem, trying to "observe & report" on a production system will likely take longer.

Comment: It does repeatedly happen on Linuxes which run virtualized and we don't really have an option to reproduce this by running 2 weeks heavy loaded tests. I haven't seen this happen on windows boxes though. You're right, it's best to catch it in dev., but I also would like to have some capability embedded into the server itself for self monitoring for the future.

Comment: RE your edit. I don't think the JVM is able to tell you how any files it has opened. That might be a nice feature for Sun to add, but until then you will have to use an external process to tell you. If you really need it inside the JVM write some code that executes lsof and returns the result.

Additionally the limit of open files can be altered. For example in Linux you can modify the /etc/security/limits.conf file.

Comment: bramp, thank.. What is a default max nof handles linux can grant to a single process? I look at my default ubuntu installation and limits.conf if pretty much empty, I presume it uses some defaults..

Comment: reply to myself - the default is 1024

Comment: Do you use a mapview? I was able to reproduce it with a mapview running on ICS, scrolling the mapview for some time.

Answer (score 33):

You didn't say which OS you are running on, but if you are running on Linux you can use the lsof command

```
lsof -p <pid of jvm>
```

That will list all the files opened by the JVM. Or if you are running on Windows you can [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which will show all the open files for all the processes.

Doing this will hopefully allow you to narrow down which bit of the code is keeping the files open.

Comment: Good idea. Check the flags you can pass to 'lsof' for repeating every X seconds.

Comment: I've added the comment about Linixes., thanks for the lsof tip!

Comment: I'd be interested to know if my solution helped you track down the problem. Also if it isn't confidential or too much hassle could you explain what caused the problem in the end?

Comment: I experience the same issue and have also judiciously closed all of my file handles, but periodically will get about 10,000 entries listed in `lsof` which the `man` page says is POSIX Semaphore. Any clue what JDK uses `PSXSEM` for? `java    36809  smm 9907r  PSXSEM              0t0          kcms00008FC901624000`

Comment: lsof -p <pid of jvm> works for me too.

I see that the list of open files increase constantly UNTIL the garbage collector runs or when I manually run the GC with jconsole.

I've considered doing a System.gc() but it increases response times considerably.

Comment: bramp, I am dissappointed to find such answer on almost 50k view question. Question and answers with this view count normally have hundreds of upvotes, not 18.

Answer (score 24):

Since you are on Linux, I'd suggest, that you check the /proc-Filesystem. Inside proc, you will find a folder with the PID of your process containing a folder calld 'fd'. If your process id is 1234, the path is be

```
/proc/1234/fd
```

Inside that folder, you will find links to all opened files (do a 'ls -l'). Usually, you can tell by the filename which library / code might open and not close the file.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful but what I'm after is something which will avoid digging into a file system or OS. I want the JVM process to tell me why is it "sick", the reason I want it is to spare users the headache is something goes wrong.

Answer (score 16):

So, full answer (I combined answers from @phisch and @bramp).
If you want to check all processes, you should use `sudo`. Also it's nice to save result to file - lsof is not cheap + this file could be useful for further investigation.

```
sudo lsof > lsof.log
```

Show bad guys (with **UPDATE** from @Arun's comment):

```
cat lsof.log | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $5}' | sort | uniq |awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5

    2687 114970 java
    131 127992 nginx
    109 128005 nginx
    105 127994 nginx
    103 128019 nginx
```

Save list of file descriptors to file as well:

```
sudo ls -l /proc/114970/fd > fd.log
```

Show top open files:

```
cat fd | awk '{ print $11 }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n20
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really useful! I think you forgot a piece in the third command, though: it should be `sudo ls -l /proc/114970/fd > fd.log`

Comment: @ocramot, you're welcome! p.s. you were right, I fixed my answer.

Comment: The first command is wrong which just uses lsof and groups . It gives a lot of duplicate file handles for the same fd with different tid.  I think those tids are in killed state but lsof shows it because it can still find it. Please correct this answer

Comment: First command should be as follows. 
`code` 
sudo lsof > lsof.log  && cat lsof.log | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $5}' | sort | uniq |awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20

Comment: @ArunGeorge can you explain first `awk` + `sort` + `uniq` + second `awk`? In my case my command worked fine (without duplicates), but maybe it depends on environment/application.

Comment: Yes, that is to remove the tids(Thread Ids). yeah its difference because of environment. By default lsof without any args shows duplicate file handles . This is explained in lsof documentation. There is a TID column which shows the thread id and they list all the threads which access the file handles. The count I got from your command and lsof -p <id-of-java> was very different . 29000 vs 714 . This is what I am talking about - https://github.com/draios/sysdig/issues/300

Answer (score 10):

You can change the limit of opened files by adding the following to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* soft nofile 2048 # Set the limit according to your needs
* hard nofile 2048
```

Then you can reload the configuration using `sysctl -p` on the shell. Check [this article](http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2007/04/too-many-open-files.html).

Just for completeness you can verify what is the current limit for opened files using: `ulimit -n`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MacOS

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles <hard> <soft>
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 200000
```