# why does this error occur? :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dir/myfile.txt (Too many open files)

Tags: java

I've written an application that runs flawlessly in windows, and throws this error on unix.

Generally, I dont understand why I'm getting this error!  I create a single file and .append text to it.  After I've appended a couple thousand lines I got this error...

Any insight would be appreciated.

Nothing in the javadoc listed this (too many files open) error: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html.

And this post didn't help me:
[Too many open files: how many are open, what they are, and how many can the JVM open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272908/java-io-filenotfoundexception-too-many-open-files).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe if you posted some of your code, you could hope for a meaningful answer...

Comment: How often are you opening the file? Once, or once for every line written? Or you sure you are closing it each time?

Comment: once for the entire application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code this is guess work, but most likely you are creating a new `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream` object each time you append, but neglect to call `close()` on these objects, which eventually causes you to run out of file descriptors (an OS level resource that is independant from memory and thus not adequately handled by garbage collection, requiring manual release).

To solve this, either keep a single Stream/Writer around and use it instead of creating a new one each time (this would probably be faster as well), or call `close()` each time you're done appending.

Comment: Ah good tip. Might have use to this. Although we do not open files that much though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you accidentally open a new file handle for each append? The limits vary with OSs. But how about posting some code - it's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but no, Im not opening a new file handle for each line write

Answer (score 0):

In linux environments this usually is capped with the flag 'ulimit'. It basically handles at OS level how many files you may open at a time. If you have a lot of dependencies, it might be that they need to be loaded and you can exceed the maximum easiliy that way.

Try setting the ulimit to 4096 before running your app and try again.

Edit:
See http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/x4733.html for more information